# graphviz basic ruler: number positioning

Tags: graphviz

I just want to create a basic ruler with numbers next to the dashes

Am I using dot wrong or what is the matter?

What would be a better approach?

[rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5K4Q.png)
[image]

```
digraph timeline {
        node [fixedsize=true height=.01 label="" shape=box width=.1 xlp="100,0"]
        edge [arrowhead=none arrowtail=none]
        1 -> 2 [xlabel=1]
        2 -> 3 [xlabel=2]
        3 -> 4 [xlabel=3]
        4 -> 5 [xlabel=4]
        5 -> 6 [xlabel=5]
        6 -> 7 [xlabel=6]
        7 -> 8 [xlabel=7]
        8 -> 9 [xlabel=8]
        9 -> 10 [xlabel=9]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dot is not well suited for this - I'd try gpic.  But is this close enough[image]?

```
digraph timeline {
 size="2,12!"
 ratio=fill

        node [fixedsize=true height=.01 label="" shape=box width=.1 xlp="100,0"]
        edge [arrowhead=none arrowtail=none]
    0  [label=""]
        1  [label="1"]
        2  [label="2   "]
        3  [label="3   "]
        4  [label="4   "]
        5  [label="5   "]
        6  [label="6   "]
        7  [label="7   "]
        8  [label="8   "]
        9  [label="9   "]
    0->1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9
}
```